# Hiding User from Last Command

Tags: linux, users

Is there any way to hide a particular user's login entry from other users who run the `last` command?

Comment: Can you be more specific? Your question is pretty ambiguous.

Comment: Are you saying you want to keep the "login entry" out of a particular user's history?  What do you mean by "login entry"? When you log into the machine, `login` doesn't go into your history.

Comment: He means the `last` command. He wants to be able to edit `[uw]tmp` or something like that, to hide his tracks.

Comment: i want to hide or block particular user's logged information from the linux box.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The output of `last(1)` comes from the traditional `wtmp` file (usually `/var/log/wtmp`). As you might imagine, this file isn't writeable by ordinary users (on this box, it belongs to `root:wtmp`).

Traditionally, the `getty` was responsible for maintaining `wtmp`, but these days it's PAM, by means of `pam_lastlog.so`, which also maintains `/var/log/lastlog`.

If you're the computer's superuser, you can go to `/etc/pam.d` and comment out the `pam_lastlog.so` line from wherever it appears in there, as appropriate. On my machine, it's used only in the `login` file. Of course, if you're the computer's superuser, you can also replace `last` and `lastlog` with a wrapper script that does something like `last.orig | fgrep -v some_user`.

If you're *not* the computer's superuser, and the site you're on uses this scheme, there's nothing you can do about it. In terms of both legality and permissions, you can't stop the system from logging your logins and logouts.

Comment: There are, of course, *always* ways around things, but discussing them is against my religious beliefs.

Answer (score 3):

The `useradd` command comes with an `-l` option not to add the username that you're going to add to the last login log file.

Answer (score 1):

you can hide by modifying the last login information file if you have the root privilege account. like

> /var/log/wtmp

it will show the blank of last log information.

Answer (score 0):

`ssh you@host /bin/sh -is` - at the price of lacking a PTY.

Answer (score 0):

A fast solution is to "disable" `last` for all normal users by `chmod o-r /var/log/wtmp`.

In this case, you might also be interested in running `chmod o-r /var/log/lastlog` to disable the `lastlog` command.